# Git rebase, multiple times - strange conflicts

Tags: git

I have a problem of rebase on already rebased branch.

The scenario is:
- I've made a branch from master, worked on it, and after time, made rebase on master (and that's ok)
- I've continued my work on that branch and put new commits
- I've done my work and now I wanted to rebase again on master to cleanup some working commits (squash) and to make sure that no merge conflicts will occur with master during marge by pull request.

And now I've a problem that I do no understand: many conflicts with files that only exists in my branch (it looks like it compare files changes commit by commit and require me to merge it). After resolve, and continue each next commit has conflicts. After a few fixes just aborted rebase as it has no sense to me.

I tried to drop commits that has been already took on first rebase, but it doesn't help. The strange thing is, that I don't see the first commit created as merge result on first rebase (it is on history on my branch, but it is not seen in editor when it shows me commit to get on rebase).

What am I doing wrong ? Generally I think, I want to continue rebase from last rebase commit, not from first commit.

Comment: Short answer: rebase *drops* merge commits. You must re-perform all merge resolutions, if you did them in merge commits earlier. `git rerere` can be useful here but this is a symptom of a development process that's getting out of hand.

Comment: Hmm. It will be expected to re-perform merge from scratch, but it ask me to resolve conflicts that doesn't exists on first merge. For ex.: first commit has new file with class, second some changes on that class. On rebase I have merge conflict on this files (both changed, what is not true), why ?

Comment: For a full answer, we'd have to know a lot more about the situation, so as to know which commits are being copied when. Because rebase removes merges, it also flattens commits brought in *via* merges. The complexity depends on the input graph. Using `-p` (`--preserve-merges`) with an interactive rebase changes the picture considerably, but the existing `-p` is not good; the new fancier `-r` / `--rebase-merges` in 2.19 is better, but still tricky.

Comment: `--preserve-merges` makes a little mess but `--rebase-merges` seems to do work. Thx.